# having difficulty writing this in LINQ

Tags: linq

The application is a basic stock-analysis app.

The data-set looks like this:

`ABC, True,  21/09/2012, 101.34

ABC, False, 21/09/2012, 202.45

CDE, True,  21/09/2012, 345.67

ABC, True,  22/09/2012. 456.78

`
The SQL is here:

```
SELECT TickerCode, Australian from Stk_ClosingPrices group by TickerCode,
 Australian having count(*) >= @daysToAverageOver order by TickerCode
```

What I would like as a result would be grouping by the first two fields,and a count of how many in each group.  For the above that would be:

ABC, True,  2
ABC, False, 1
CDE, True,  1

And then I would like to return only those with Count > parameter passed in.

The algorithm is going to calculate a 20-day moving average, so in English the query is 'Give me the keys of stocks with more than 20 data records'

This is how far I have got, but I can't get the Count right, it is always the same for every group.

```
  var query = (from cp in this.ObjectContext.stk_ClosingPrices group cp by new {
       cp.TickerCode, cp.Australian
   }
   into grp
    select new {
       grp.Key.TickerCode, grp.Key.Australian,
       Count = grp.Distinct()
   }).ToList();
```

I have seen an example similar with a **grp.Sum(Quantity)** but could not seem to be able to re-cast that to .Count() predicate.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var query1 = (from cp in this.ObjectContext.stk_ClosingPrices group cp by new {
   cp.TickerCode, cp.Australian
}
into grp
select new {
   grp.Key.TickerCode, grp.Key.Australian,
   Count = grp.Count()
});

var results = (from r in query where r.Count > 20 orderby r.TickerCode select r).ToList();
```

Will actually produce SQL like

```
SELECT TickerCode, Australian, Count
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, TickerCode, Australian
    FROM  Stk_ClosingPrices
    GROUP BY TickerCode, Australian
    ) AS t1
WHERE t1.Count > 20
Order By t1.TickerCode
```